# Logging in google closure and dumping objects to console like console.log(myObject)

Tags: debugging, logging, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I like to dump objects to console sometimes so I can click on it and inspect it. For example:

```
console.log(document.body);
```

In closere it seems the logs log everything to console under every group (Errors, warning, Info...). But does not dump the object. Instead the formatters turn it into a string first and then display that.

Using goog.debug.expose helps somewhat but might create huge amounts of text instead of neat clickable line to use for inspection like FireBug/Chrome does.

To solve this I have commented out some code in goog/debug/logger.js

```
// goog.global['console']['timeStamp'](msg);
...
// goog.global['console']['markTimeline'](msg);
```

When I log I use the google.debug.Logger for short messages and wrote a function for dumping objects to console. Here is an example: (some of the variables are global so I can play with it in FireBug)

```
goog.require('goog.debug');
goog.require('goog.debug.DivConsole');
goog.require('goog.debug.Logger');
var con;
var l;
// dump object to firebug or chrome console for clickable inspection
var dumpToConsole=function(o){
    try{
        goog.global['console']['log'](o);
    }catch(e){
        l.warn("Cannot dump object to console."+
             goog.debug.deepExpose(o, true));
    }
}
var demoDebug = function() {
    var el=document.createElement("div");
    el.style.maxHeight="50px";
    el.style.overflow="auto";
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    con=new goog.debug.DivConsole(el);
    con.setCapturing(true);
    l = goog.debug.Logger.getLogger('myApp.translate');
    l.info("info");
    l.log("log");
    //dump object to console:
    dumpToConsole(document.body);
}
...
//in another script block later in the page:
demoDebug();
```

My question is:

Is this a good way to do the logging?

Plan to put all the logging code in `if (goog.DEBUG) {` block so it won't be compiled when deploying the application.

Comment: hi, Did you ever implement logging using closure then ?